# How to make a div height and width equal to screen width and height?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want my first **div "panel-1"** to take the full width and height of screen.
I have been trying to break this problem from 3 days.

I tried `height :100%` & `width:100` on parent. Then `position:relative` on section and `position:absolute` on div. I tried various other solutions on stack overflow. But none helped.

I created a fiddle at:-

https://jsfiddle.net/81uo3zfc/

```
<div id="navigation_panel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="technologies.html">Technologies</a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <section>
        <div id="panel-1">
            <p class="lazyText">Hey!</p>
            <p class="lazyText">Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
            <p class="colorTransition">sit amet consectetur.</p>

            <a class="nextBtn" id="nextBtn-1" href="#panel-2">Let's Go <img class="emoji" src="images/hand.svg" alt="Continue Icon"></a>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div id="panel-2">
            <p class="lazyText">Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p class="normal lazyText"> dolor, sit amet </p>
            <p class="normal">consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, a.</p>

            <a class="nextBtn" id="nextBtn-2" href="#panel-3">Roger That <img class="emoji" src="images/hand.svg" alt="Continue Icon"></a>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div id="panel-3">
            <p class="lazyText">Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p class="normal lazyText"> dolor, sit amet </p>
            <p class="normal">consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, a.</p>

            <a class="nextBtn" name="nextBtn-3" data="tech" href="javascript:;">Tech Person <img class="emoji" src="images/tech.svg" alt="Tech Icon"></a>

            <a class="nextBtn" name="nextBtn-3" data="nontech" href="javascript:;" style="margin-left: 10px;">Non Tech Person <img class="emoji" src="images/non_tech.svg" alt="Non Tech Icon"></a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Please help. I am new to CSS. And i really tried solving it on my own. But failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem you ran into is, that the `%` sizes relate to the last offset parent (the body or the next relative/absolute/fixed element in the parent chain).
Since your offset parent is using the full screen height, elements using `100%` will scale to that size too.

The way to go would be a flex layout.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Set the flex layout to the parent element of the navigation, set the direction to column and size it to screen height. The navigation will remain static size by adding `flex-grow:0; flex-shrink:0`.

The content will be shown in a additional `.content` container, wich takes up the rest of the screen space using `flex-grow:1;`. The entries will will then be scaled to the height of the `.content` container using `height:100%;`.

The footer can also be part of this setup, by placing it in the `.sizer` container and set `flex-grow:0; flex-shrink:0`

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

.sizer {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  flex-grow:1;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#navigation_panel
{
  background-color: #15598f;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

#navigation_panel>ul
{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navigation_panel>ul>li
{
  display: inline;
  margin : 2%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#navigation_panel>ul>li>a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

section
{
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 90%;
  height:100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#panel-1,#panel-2,#panel-3,#panel-4,#panel-5,#panel-6
{
  border: 4px solid #27a9e0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#panel-1 p,#panel-2 p:nth-child(1),#panel-3 p:nth-child(1),#panel-4 p:nth-child(1),#panel-5 p:nth-child(1),#panel-6 p:nth-child(1)
{
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.normal{
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.normal-small{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.nextBtn
{
  background-color: #15598f;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;

  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}


.emoji
{
  width: 25px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.emoji:hover
{
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}


.AdditionalList>li>a
{
  color : #1b8ab9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #27a9e066;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: auto;
}

.AdditionalList>li
{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


footer{
  margin: 5% 2% 0% 0%;
}


.third{
  width: 33%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #242f4a;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/*Technologies Css*/

.techlist>li{
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizer">
  <div id="navigation_panel">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="technologies.html">Technologies</a></li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <section>
      <div id="panel-1">
        <p class="lazyText">Hey!</p>
        <p class="lazyText">Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
        <p class="colorTransition">sit amet consectetur.</p>

        <a class="nextBtn" id="nextBtn-1" href="#panel-2">Let's Go <img class="emoji" src="images/hand.svg" alt="Continue Icon"></a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div id="panel-2">
        <p class="lazyText">Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p class="normal lazyText"> dolor, sit amet </p>
        <p class="normal">consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, a.</p>

        <a class="nextBtn" id="nextBtn-2" href="#panel-3">Roger That <img class="emoji" src="images/hand.svg" alt="Continue Icon"></a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div id="panel-3">
        <p class="lazyText">Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p class="normal lazyText"> dolor, sit amet </p>
        <p class="normal">consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, a.</p>

        <a class="nextBtn" name="nextBtn-3" data="tech"  href="javascript:;">Tech Person <img class="emoji" src="images/tech.svg" alt="Tech Icon"></a>

        <a class="nextBtn" name="nextBtn-3"  data="nontech"  href="javascript:;" style="margin-left: 10px;">Non Tech Person <img class="emoji" src="images/non_tech.svg" alt="Non Tech Icon"></a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! Thank You. Thanks a lot Sir. It solved my problem. Didn't know Flex Box could do that. Could you please explain. What mistake i was doing?
And how you and Flex Box corrected it.

Comment: Hi, i have updated the answer, if you have any more questions please drop them here. Basically flex box can do intelligent resizing of child elements based on their size. By setting flex-grow/-shrink to 0 you can have elements with fixed size, while all the others will share the left over space. It is a useful feature and can solve a lot of problems. You might want to read a bit into that ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width: 100vw;` and `height: 100vh` to exactly match the screen/viewport size.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to attach the header with the code. I edited the question. Please check the new JS Fiddle. Your code did the job. But i have a header in page. And the CSS code now makes panel-1 overflow the screen height. imgur.com/twgozpF

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
**css**
html,body{
    /*height: 100%;*/
    margin:0;
    /*border:1px solid black;*/
}

#navigation_panel
{
    background-color: #15598f;
    padding: 2%;
    margin: 0;
}

#navigation_panel>ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#navigation_panel>ul>li
{
    display: inline;
    margin : 2%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#navigation_panel>ul>li>a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

section
{
    width:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    height: 100%;
}

#panel-1,#panel-2,#panel-3,#panel-4,#panel-5,#panel-6
{
    border: 4px solid #27a9e0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 4%;
    height: 90%;
    max-height: 600px !important;

}
#panel-1{
height: calc(100vh - 176px);
max-height: inherit !important;

}

#panel-1 p,#panel-2 p:nth-child(1),#panel-3 p:nth-child(1),#panel-4 p:nth-child(1),#panel-5 p:nth-child(1),#panel-6 p:nth-child(1)
{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.normal{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.normal-small{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.nextBtn
{
    background-color: #15598f;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
}


.emoji
{
    width: 25px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.emoji:hover
{
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}


.AdditionalList>li>a
{
    color : #1b8ab9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #27a9e066;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: auto;
}

.AdditionalList>li
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


footer{
    margin: 5% 2% 0% 0%;
}


.third{
    width: 33%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #242f4a;
    color: #ffffff;
}


/*Technologies Css*/

.techlist>li{
    font-size: 34px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to attach the header with the code. I edited the question. Please check the new JS Fiddle. 
Your code did the job. But i have a header in page. And the CSS code now makes panel-1overflow the screen height.
https://imgur.com/twgozpF

Comment: Sir, It is still not working. On Responsive layout in Chrome Tools, It works for width < 1180px. But for greater width. It overflows. My Screen width is 1400px and it is overflowing. It tried overflow hidden. But the lower portion becomes cutted out and unscrollable.

Comment: you adjust for all resolution height: calc(100vh - 176px); .. 176 is header height

Comment: I did that but it is still overflowing. Please Help.

Comment: pls share you website url i ll check and let you know

Comment: sir. Bellian Sir answer solved my problem. Thanks for helping. Thanks for taking out time and helping me. It means a lot. Want to connect on Linkedin. Please send profile link. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Set this:

```
#panel-1{
width: 100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set this:

```
#panel-1{
position:absolute; 
top:0px; 
left:0px; 
bottom:0px; 
right:0px;
}
```